# Linear model - choice of predictor and response variable when interaction term included

Tags: r, regression, interaction, linear-model

I am interested in analysing the correlation between two parameters (Sepal.Length and Sepal.Width for this example) and how they vary with the values of a third continuous parameter. I have no reason to choose one of Sepal.Length or Sepal.Width as the predictor over the other. This would not be a problem if I did not have the interaction term since I get the same result either way:

```
data(iris)

fit1<-lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width, data=iris)
fit2<-lm(Sepal.Width~Sepal.Length, data=iris)
summary(fit1);summary(fit2)


# Adjusted R-squared:  0.007159 for fit1 and fit2
```

However, if I include the interaction term, the choice of response variable changes the result:

```
fit3<-lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width*Petal.Length, data=iris)
fit4<-lm(Sepal.Width~Sepal.Length*Petal.Length, data=iris)
summary(fit3);summary(fit4)

# Adjusted R-squared:  0.8404 for fit3 and adjusted R-squared:  0.4478 for fit4
```

Above all, the slope changes and its statistical significance:

```
Fit3 Sepal.Width:Petal.Length est: -0.07701    p-val: 0.07571
Fit4: Sepal.Length:Petal.Length est: 0.01795    p-val: 0.413063
```

Is there anyway of obtaining an estimate for the effect of an interaction term without having to choose an predictor and response variable?

Comment: If you are interested in correlation, why are you fitting a regression model? It appears you should actually be interested in partial correlation coefficients.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would rather not use a regression model but I am unaware of a correlation analysis that allow me to compare two parameters along a gradient. I will look into partial correlation coefficients.

Comment: It seems that partial correlation allows one to control a variable while testing the correlation between two other variables (more akin to a random effect in a mixed model). I am looking for something more like a correlogram where I can test or express the correlation as a function of a third continuous variable.

Comment: I think you can use a SEM for this but that is beyond my expertise.

Comment: Please double-check the code you've provided for `fit2` and `fit4`. As I write this the formulas seem to be identical with those for  `fit1` and `fit3`, respectively, but I think you want the dependent variable to be `sepal.width` in `fit2` and `fit4`.

Comment: Thank you, the code has now been corrected.